# Parse log in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, logging

I'm trying to parse a log file in Python, the file contains thousands of this line:

RAM 2822/3956MB (lfb 106x4MB) SWAP 107/1978MB (cached 0MB) IRAM 0/252kB(lfb 252kB) CPU [24%@102,23%@204,off,off] EMC_FREQ 3%@1600 GR3D_FREQ 0%@76 VIC_FREQ 0%@140 APE 25 PLL@30C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@42.5C thermal@31.5C POM_5V_IN 2000/2000 POM_5V_GPU 38/38 POM_5V_CPU 115/115

Where I need to extract the values of POM_5V_IN and POM_5V_CPU, so, 2000/2000 and 115/115 respectively. Below is my code, however, it doesn't return those values. Probably, I'm missing something with regex syntax.

```
import re
newFile = open('datasets/consum_amt.log','r')
for line in newFile.readlines():
    if ('POM_5V_IN' in line): 
        P_in = re.compile(r'\{\"POM_5V_IN\" (0-9)\}')#parse POM IN
      
    else if ('POM_5V_CPU' in line):
        P_cpu = re.compile(r'\{\"POM_5V_CPU\" (0-9)\}')#parse POM CPU
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This any use?

```
str1 = "RAM 2822/3956MB (lfb 106x4MB) SWAP 107/1978MB (cached 0MB) IRAM 0/252kB(lfb 252kB) CPU [24%@102,23%@204,off,off] EMC_FREQ 3%@1600 GR3D_FREQ 0%@76 VIC_FREQ 0%@140 APE 25 PLL@30C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@42.5C thermal@31.5C POM_5V_IN 2000/2000 POM_5V_GPU 38/38 POM_5V_CPU 115/115"

ind1a = str.find(str1, "POM_5V_IN", 0)
ind1b = str.find(str1, "POM_5V_GPU",0)
P_in = str1[ind1a+10, ind1b]  #Offsetting for length of "POM_5V_IN", could of course do that programmatically if you wanted

ind2 = str.find(str1, "POM_5V_CPU", 0)
P_cpu = str1[ind2+11:]  #Same offsetting as above
```

It is relying on POM_5V_IN values being trailed by the string "POM_5V_GPU and on the POM_5V_CPU being the last entry of the string. So if that's not the case it'd need some work.

Answer (score 0):

Considering `line` as :

```
line = "RAM 2822/3956MB (lfb 106x4MB) SWAP 107/1978MB (cached 0MB) IRAM 0/252kB(lfb 252kB) CPU [24%@102,23%@204,off,off] EMC_FREQ 3%@1600 GR3D_FREQ 0%@76 VIC_FREQ 0%@140 APE 25 PLL@30C CPU@32C PMIC@100C GPU@31C AO@42.5C thermal@31.5C POM_5V_IN 2000/2000 POM_5V_GPU 38/38 POM_5V_CPU 115/115"
```

You can use one regex with multiple capture groups like this :

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"POM_5V_IN\s(?P<IN>[0-9]+/[0-9]+)\s.*POM_5V_CPU\s(?P<CPU>[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
```

You can access the results like this :

```
>>> regex.search(line).group('IN')
'2000/2000'
>>> regex.search(line).group('CPU')
'115/115'
```

The name of the capture groups is between `<` and `>` in the regular expression. You can play with that regex [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=POM_5V_IN%5Cs(%3FP%3CIN%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B%2F%5B0-9%5D%2B)%5Cs.*POM_5V_CPU%5Cs(%3FP%3CCPU%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B%2F%5B0-9%5D%2B)&test_string=RAM%202822%2F3956MB%20(lfb%20106x4MB)%20SWAP%20107%2F1978MB%20(cached%200MB)%20IRAM%200%2F252kB(lfb%20252kB)%20CPU%20%5B24%25%40102%2C23%25%40204%2Coff%2Coff%5D%20EMC_FREQ%203%25%401600%20GR3D_FREQ%200%25%4076%20VIC_FREQ%200%25%40140%20APE%2025%20PLL%4030C%20CPU%4032C%20PMIC%40100C%20GPU%4031C%20AO%4042.5C%20thermal%4031.5C%20POM_5V_IN%202000%2F2000%20POM_5V_GPU%2038%2F38%20POM_5V_CPU%20115%2F115&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that should work.
Notes:

- the if isn't needed. Also `else if` is `elif` in python
- remove the curly brackets and extra quotes from the regular expressions
- change the contents to the group capture to:
  capture one-or-more digits followed by a forward slash followed by one-or-more-digits
- move the re.compile() statements before the loop because they only need to happen once

Your example was close.  After compiling the regular expression with `re.compile` then call it with either `re.match()` or `re.search()`.

```
import re
newFile = open('datasets/consum_amt.log','r')
P_in = re.compile(r'POM_5V_IN (\d+[/]\d+)')#parse POM IN
P_cpu = re.compile(r'POM_5V_CPU (\d+[/]\d+)')#parse POM CPU

for line in newFile.readlines():
    found_in = P_in.search(line)
    if found_in:
        print(found_in.groups()[0])
  
    found_cpu = P_cpu.search(line)
    if found_cpu:
        print(found_cpu.groups()[0])
```